# Show window at right-bottom of screen (above taskbar)

Tags: c, mfc

I want to show my TopMost window right-bottom of screen (above taskbar)

Here is what I have tried:

```
this->SetWindowPos(&this->wndBottom, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Which shows at center of screen

Comment: You are giving 'SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE', so it keeps current position and size. So what is current position and size?

Comment: Let it be dynamic using `Screen.Width - Wnd.Width` and `Screen.Height - Taskbar.Height - Wnd.Height`

Comment: Why aren't you telling the system where to place the window? It's not going to read your mind.

Comment: I have a formula for the top(x,y) of window, shown above. Just need to translate to MFC code

Comment: Why do you assume that the taskbar is at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA...)` to find the desktop rectangle (area excluding the toolbar) then set window position with `SWP_NOSIZE` flag:

```
CRect rcDesktop;
::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, NULL, &rcDesktop, NULL);

CRect rw;
GetWindowRect(&rw);

SetWindowPos(0, rcDesktop.right - rw.Width(), rcDesktop.bottom - rw.Height(), 0, 0, 
    SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: This solution only applies to single-monitor setups.